# How Can I add Taxonomy Name and It's URL in SiteNavigationElement Schema?

Tags: wordpress, schema, taxonomy

I am new to stackoverflow and also in wordpress coding. I am learning. I have a taxonomy and I want to add all taxonomy and it's URL in SiteNavigationElement Schema. anyone cal help me to provide the solutions.

below is my code

```php
<script type="application/ld+json">
    
    {
            <?php
$custom_terms = get_the_terms('dealstore' );
$term_link = get_term_link( $custom_terms );
foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
         );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
while( $query->have_posts() ) :
$query->the_post(); ?>
<?php if ($query->current_post +1 == $query->post_count) : ?>
   {
            "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
            "@id": "#navigation",
            "name": "<?php echo $query->name; ?>",
            "url": "<?php echo esc_url( $term_link );?>"
        }
<?php else : ?>
    {
            "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
            "@id": "#navigation",
            "name": "<?php echo $query->name; ?>",
            "url": "<?php echo esc_url( $term_link );?>"
        },
<?php endif;  ?>


      
<?php endwhile;

endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); } ?>
            
        }
</script>
```

Can It be possible with IF condition ?
for example - if first taxonomy name than
it shows like below with "," (commas")

```php
{
            "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
            "@id": "#navigation",
            "name": "<?php echo $query->name; ?>",
            "url": "<?php echo esc_url( $term_link );?>"
        },
```

if last taxonomy name than it shows like below without ","(commas")

```php
{
            "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
            "@id": "#navigation",
            "name": "<?php echo $query->name; ?>",
            "url": "<?php echo esc_url( $term_link );?>"
        }
```

Comment: On which page are you adding this schema?

Comment: I am adding schema on every dealstore taxonomy page.

Comment: I will back to you.

Comment: what will be `"name": "<?php echo $query->name; ?>"`, and  `"url": "<?php echo esc_url( $term_link );?>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current taxonomy on the current page by using `get_queried_object` Put this on your taxonomy page.

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'species',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

if( !empty( $terms ) ){

    ?>

    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {   
        <?php 
            $total = count($terms);
            $i = 0;
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) { $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
                $i++;
            ?>
            {
                "@type": "SiteNavigationElement",
                "@id": "#navigation",
                "name": "<?php echo $term->name; ?>",
                "url": "<?php echo esc_url( $term_link );?>"
            }                   
        <?php if ($i != $total) echo', '; } ?>
    }
    </script>
    <?php 
}
```

Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: I think it will display only one taxonomy name. I want it with multiple taxonomy name. Can  you do with array ? thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: But if you are on the taxonomy page only one taxonomy will get.

Comment: I can get the all taxonomy and it's url with
```php
<?php 
$terms = get_terms( 'species' );
 
echo '<ul>';
 
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
 
    // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
    
    // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
        continue;
    }
 
    // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
    echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
 
echo '</ul>';

?>
```

Comment: I have posted one condition can it be possible ? can you please check my edit on question?